# Using GPO to create 2 shortcuts that link to the same page causing issues

Tags: active-directory, vpn, group-policy

My company wants to create a shortcut on the desktop that links to a certain website using chrome. However I found that some users have chrome installed under **C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application** and others have it installed under **C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application**.

I created two shortcuts with the same name linking to the same web page. It worked for some people but didn't for others, some users didn't see the shortcut whereas others would see two of the shortcut links on their desktop.

It's been a pain as well since most people have been working from home and they connect to the VPN after they log in.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: dont use native path to open Chrome, set it once as default and just create a link for the url. it does not require any browser to use it

Comment: Management doesn't want me to set the user's default browser. If I could set it to chrome, it would be a lot better

Comment: I disagree, a lot of Company has a Browser Policy. If not the management seems not to have done yet a Risk Management. However, i suggest you to create a Shortcut with the url only - else you will need a small batch file to verify the path. Which might be in my Point the easier solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a Computer policy to apply a company-wide link to All Users / Desktop - then users can't remove files accidentally.
Use the option "Create", and "Replace" if you need to update
Use Common / targeting option "File exists" to check if either the x86 or x64 folder has the "chrome.exe" file location.